# How to resolve promise when it calls using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, http, post

I do HTTP POST request with angularjs, I just want it to call it during page loads. But the response of the POST returns an promise.

How should I resolve the promise when it calls? How do I get the resolved response when page loads?

Comment: I can't understand your questions. What are the various "it" in the question. What do you mean by "when it calls". A promise doesn't call. Have you read the documentation of promises?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you ask about getting your result when making a POST request in angular. See this example, taken from angularjs docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http :

```
$http.post('/someUrl', {msg:'hello word!'}).
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Result is not available imadietelly after you make a call. Instead method `post()` returns a promise. Promises are a base concept of asynchronous programming in js. The promise is resolved as soon, as the request is complete. To utilize the results you need to call `then()` method with a proper callback. Callback will be called with the data retrieved.